# Which classes can be copied?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

In the property declaration it is possible to send the "copy" attribute. You can not use copy for all objects, but for which objects is it possible to use the copy attribute?

Comment: My book describes copy as an attribute (in the following context): @property(nonatomic, copy)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-copy` is not an attribute, it is a method.  It's OK to send `-copy` to any object that implements the [NSCopying](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol.

If you have a property, you can (should?) use the `copy` attribute if the property's type is a class that implements `NSCopying`. i.e. any class that it is OK to send `-copy` to.

Comment: My book describes copy as an attribute (in the following context):
@property(nonatomic, copy)

Comment: @Foo: Sorry, I looked at the word "send" in your question and assumed you meant the message `-send`.

Comment: @Foo: yes it is answering your question.  You asked for which objects can you use the copy attribute and I answered "any that implements `NSCopying`". If you look at the header file or documentation for any class, you'll immediately be able to see if it implements `NSCopying`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy a **class**. Copy is an instance method, it makes a clone instance out of another instance. In order for the instance to be copyable, it needs to implement `NSCopying` protocol. Some NSFundation/Cocoa classes implement it, some don't. For those that don't you have to write an implementation yourself using categories. But be careful, this can be very tricky for UI Classes.